# Are **kwargs a good choice for non-configuration data in __init__?

Tags: python, constructor, keyword-argument

I'm thinking of using `**kwargs` in an unusual way: as data provider and not as overloading substituting tool. In this way all keyword arguments should be of one type, for example specifically formed tuple, and no way else. In example:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    '''All **kwargs should be in ("string", 1, True) form'''
    def __init__(self, some_param, **kwargs):
        self.param = some_param
        for arg in kwargs.itervalues():
            if not isinstance(arg[0], str):
            ...

        self.some_dict = kwargs
```

Is it OK to do so? I feel... strange, it seems uncanonical.

Comment: Are you familiar with `*args` too?

Comment: @ulidtko Yep. Basically question is about both, but eventually I ended up with **kwargs, because they are more complex.

Comment: I think this code does not what you expect. kwargs is a dict, and its keys are always strings. If you iterate over it (for arg in kwargs), arg is always a string, so arg[0] is also always a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See what the `dict` constructor does in Python:

```
>>> dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
{'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Also a "creative" use of keyword arguments. If this works for a standard type, and makes sense in your application, go for it.